# Use regex search in mysql within a comma separated string with regex patterns?

Tags: mysql, regex

I wanna find out if 11624 match any of the zipcodes/zipcode series in column shipping_zipcodes:

```
SELECT * FROM providers WHERE '11624' RLIKE shipping_zipcodes
```

My query works with 11624 and 116[0-9]{2} in shipping_zipcodes but not with 11624,11625 or 116[0-9]{2},11625 in shipping_zipcodes.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need `WHERE shipping_zipcodes LIKE '%11624%'`? Or `REGEXP '116[0-9]{2}'`?

Comment: That will work for the row 122, not with row 51. =/

Comment: What do you mean? `51` has no `116` nor `11624` inside it.

Comment: 51 should match 11624 with the regex 116[0-9]{2}

Comment: No way, `116[0-9]{2}` cannot and should not ever match `51`.

Comment: What i mean is that 11624 should match 116[0-9]{2} which is in shipping_zipcodes for row 51. =)

Comment: `116[0-9]{2}` matches `11624` **not** vice versa.

Comment: Yes, thats true. =)
What im looking for is to get both rows, 51 and 122 back from my query.

So I guess the best way is to normalize the values so i have multiple rows instead of a comma separated list.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> SELECT '11624' REGEXP "^(116[0-9]{2}|11625)$";
+----------------------------------------+
| '11624' REGEXP "^(116[0-9]{2}|11625)$" |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      1 |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that I had to change the syntax you save in `shipping_zipcodes` -- Most important: `|` instead of `,`.

You might be able to do without the anchoring or the parens -- if you can assume all input values (eg `11624`) are exactly 5 digits.  If not, `CONCAT()` can be used to tack them onto what you currently have.

And you may be able to use `REPLACE()` to turn `,` into `|`:

```
mysql> SELECT '11624' REGEXP REPLACE("116[0-9]{2},11625", ',', '|');
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| '11624' REGEXP REPLACE("116[0-9]{2},11625", ',', '|') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                     1 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

But... If your list is long, the query will be slow.  Any of these require a full table scan.  If it is too slow, you need to build a table mapping individual zipcodes to providers -- and index it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case better to use FIND_IN_SET instead of REGEX:

```
SELECT * FROM providers WHERE FIND_IN_SET('11624', shipping_zipcodes) > 0;
```

Comment: Don't wanna be rude, but this is not the full answer. But thanks for the tip about FIND_IN_SET. =)

Answer (score 0):

What I think is the best answer is to normalize the table to get rid of the comma spearated list. Then I can use this query to get the result i want:

```
SELECT
    pr.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(psp.postcode ORDER BY psp.postcode ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS postcodes
FROM
    providers pr
LEFT JOIN
    providers_shipping_postcodes psp ON psp.provider_id = pr.id
WHERE
    '11624' RLIKE psp.postcode
GROUP BY
    pr.id
```